# ImportError:DLL load failed:The network name cannot be found

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I'm sorry to bother again, but now I have a problem with seaborn. When I try to use this package, I got this error:

[image: print of the image here]

[View Image in full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9OTN.png)

Here is the full error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:/Users/ana.moreira/Documents/PycharmProjects/Playing/manipulating_tables.py", line 8, in <module>
    import seaborn as sns
  File "C:\Users\ana.moreira\Documents\PycharmProjects\LP11\alergen\alergen_sfiltro\venv\lib\site-packages\seaborn\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .rcmod import *
  File "C:\Users\ana.moreira\Documents\PycharmProjects\LP11\alergen\alergen_sfiltro\venv\lib\site-packages\seaborn\rcmod.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import palettes, _orig_rc_params
  File "C:\Users\ana.moreira\Documents\PycharmProjects\LP11\alergen\alergen_sfiltro\venv\lib\site-packages\seaborn\palettes.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .utils import desaturate, set_hls_values, get_color_cycle
  File "C:\Users\ana.moreira\Documents\PycharmProjects\LP11\alergen\alergen_sfiltro\venv\lib\site-packages\seaborn\utils.py", line 7, in <module>
    from scipy import stats
  File "C:\Users\ana.moreira\Documents\PycharmProjects\LP11\alergen\alergen_sfiltro\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py", line 367, in <module>
    from .stats import *
  File "C:\Users\ana.moreira\Documents\PycharmProjects\LP11\alergen\alergen_sfiltro\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 172, in <module>
    import scipy.special as special
  File "C:\Users\ana.moreira\Documents\PycharmProjects\LP11\alergen\alergen_sfiltro\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.py", line 641, in <module>
    from ._ufuncs import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The network name cannot be found.
```

If someone could help, many thanks.

Comment: In general you need to give more info if you want people to be able to help you. Copy/paste the error message, do not take a screenshot.
What is the version of Python you use, and the version of the libraries involved in the error message (scipy and seaborn)? How did you install them?

Comment: I'm using python 3.7.1 and the scipy 1.2.0, seaborn 0.9.0. I installed them:pip intall "name of the package".

Comment: Which version of Numpy do you use? Scipy 1.2.0 specifies that `NumPy 1.15.0 [is] required`

Comment: I've installed numpy 1.15.4, and I still get the same error.

Comment: You can remove seaborn and installing it again following these instructions: https://seaborn.pydata.org/installing.html